# .NET Core v1 release compatible with ASP.NET CORE RC1?

Tags: asp.net, .net-core, asp.net-core-1.0

I am new to this ASP.NET versions and I built an app on ASP.NET CORE RC1, MVC6, EF7 & ANGULARJS. I was told that I would need to update the app to use v1 release of .NET Core instead of a release candidate.

I don't know much but that the change was significant with RC1 to RC2, but what do I have to do to update the app for it to work for the .NET Core v1 release?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The changes from RC1 to the recent RTM release are fairly substantial and contain lots of breaking changes (i.e. different API calls, differently named namespaces/packages, etc.) and there isn't really any type of automatic migration process.

**Regarding Migrating Your Application**

If you want to attempt to migrate your application to the recent release, you should consider checking out Shawn Wildermuth's blog posts on the process :

- [Migrating from ASP.NET Core RC1 to RC2](https://wildermuth.com/2016/05/17/Converting-an-ASP-NET-Core-RC1-Project-to-RC2)
- [Migrating from ASP.NET Core RC2 to RTM](https://wildermuth.com/2016/06/27/Converting-ASP-NET-Core-1-0-RC2-to-RTM-Bits)

He goes into quite a bit of detail on all of the changes that you need to make that *should* get your application where it needs to be.

The other option would be to spin up a new ASP.NET Core application and manually migrate some of your existing code into it. This may not necessarily be feasible depending on the size of your project, but for smaller projects it'll likely be an easier and safer route.

Comment: Operative word "should".  You can end up spending a ton of time updating your projects.  And even if you are successful (a big if), you are still stuck with the RC1 project properties page.  If you want to do a full proof upgrade, uninstall Visual Studio 2015 and any RC1 components.  Re-install VS 2015 with Update 3 and install ASP.NET Core 1.0 RTM and Visual Studio tooling preview 2.  Then copy your RC1 code into a new project and make the adjustments for the new namespaces.